# Local MongoDB implementation for Electron App

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im currently building a web app heavily based on **MongoDB** and **Mongoose** for the web app backend. The app will also have a desktop version based on **electron**. However as far as I’ve researched, including stackoverflow, you can’t package **MongoDB** with an electron app. The app might not be connected to the internet all the time. And hence I need a local store for it as well. This is where I want to use something like **CouchDB** or **PouchDB**.

The implementation I have come up with is this:

1. Store the data in a CouchDB/PouchDB
2. Check if there’s an Internet connection
3. If a connection can be established match the online MongoDB with the local CouchDB/PouchDB and add any entries not present in the database to MongoDB.

What I’d like to ask is if there’s a betterway to go about this?

Comment: I have worked in a simular situation where we used flat json files as a repo (git managed), and then enriched it further with a liteDB.. (.net env) Just for the portability of it. But I think it's going to boil down to the right tool for the job. Nothing wrong with your suggestion of CouchDB as a 'proxy' / 'temp datastore at all imo.